# IBM RQM: execute/run the test case execution record (TCER) via POST operation using REST API

Tags: rest, rational-team-concert

We are planning to create the test cases drafted in Excel file using RQMExcelWordExport tool . It is a tedious task to manually update the test case execution result status. Also, it is quite difficult to do a retrospection of the execution history result of the same test case.

Can anyone help us on this with the following :

1. How to get all the test case execution record (TCER) with respect to test plan id via REST GET ?
2. How to execute/run the test case execution record (TCER) via POST operation in REST API /
   or we can able to update TCER status through RQMExcelWordExport tool.

Regards,
Sujata